# 'the very strong acid, chloric acid' vs. 'a very strong acid, chloric acid'

Tags: articles, definite-article, discourse-markers

> Chlorine(VII) oxide reacts with water to give **the** very strong acid, chloric(VII) acid - also known as perchloric acid. ([source](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/period3/oxidesh2o.html))

I guess we can use **a** instead of **the** here:

> Chlorine(VII) oxide reacts with water to give **a** very strong acid, chloric(VII) acid - also known as perchloric acid.

After all, this is the first mention, and we're describing "chloric(VII) acid".

> Chloric acid is **a** very strong acid.

I wonder what might have nudged the author towards the use of **the** here. Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Forget about the *first mentions* "rule." Go read any magazine article on the internet and you will find that 70% of first mentions utilize the definite article.

Comment: @GoDucks - I know, it's just when I'm busy with other things, I forget exactly why we use **the** in this or that "first usage" context. So I'm curious why is it used so now.

Comment: The difference in meaning in seems like emphasis to me. *The* is more emphatic and suggests that the author will go on to talk about this type of acid.

Comment: Because it is idiomatic to do so in scientific articles (among others), seeing as how the referent will be *further defined* and *discussed*. In this context, speaking definitely about something is deemed more desirable than speaking indefinitely about something.

Comment: @GoDucks not only in scientific contexts: see "[In Scotland's realm forlorn and bare \ **the** history chanced of late \ **this** history of a wedded pair \ a chaffinch and his mate](http://www.poemhunter.com/best-poems/william-cowper/a-tale-june-1793/)" - I felt unsure about lumping these two quotations together, but I wondered why Cowper did not use **a** there. A similar appositive construction.

Comment: "*the* history" demands an explanation, as it (incorrectly) assumes the listener/reader knows what is being referred to. *What* history? The poet is aware of this; hence, the explanatory "*this* history..." in the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We often signal the topic of what we are going to talk about not with *a/an* but with *the*. **The acid Chloric(VII) acid** is the **topic** of the portion of the article following its first mention. The definite article is used because of the **discourse prominence** of the referent.

> The definite article serves a variety of functions in discourse besides the previously mentioned identifiability/familiarity. It also denotes:
>
> - the discourse prominence of an entity;...

Source: Page 151 of [Extension and its Limits](https://books.google.com/books?id=nDhQBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Search the text for "discourse prominence".

Consider also:

> An especially clear illustration of a discourse prominent entity is one
>   that is highly topical. Most interesting in this respect are entities entered
>   into the discourse with **an initial definite description in order to signal that
>   they will be topics in the subsequent portion of text** [my emphasis]

Source: *pdf* [The definite article, accessibility, and the construction of discourse referents](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~israel/Epstein-DefArt-01.pdf)

by [Richard Epstein](http://crab.rutgers.edu/~repstein/cv.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As always, the choice of article reflects the *speaker's* attitude with respect to the listener's ability to recognize what he is referring to.

A speaker who says **the strong acid, chloric acid** is, intentionally or unintentionally, projecting the attitude that he expects the listener to recognize it by name and to already be aware that the name is associated with a characteristic, namely "strong acid".

A speaker who says **a strong acid, chloric acid** is not projecting the attitude that he expects the listener to recognize the acid by name.

Comment: -1 hardly *as always*. Also, if you downvoted my answer why don't you leave a reason, or do you just serially downvote anything I post?

Comment: If one says *Have you heard about the accident on Romano Avenue?* the speaker is not "intentionally or unintentionally, projecting the attitude that he expects the listener to recognize it," (the accident) rather...

Comment: ...he is signalling to the auditor that he knows the auditor cannot identify the referent and that he is now going to identify the referent for the auditor by making it the topic of what he wants or intends to talk about.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote. At least I didn't recall downvoting it. To test, I just tried to dowvote your answer now, and the attempt was successful. So I hadn't. The listener may or may not have heard about that accident referred to as "*the* accident". But for the speaker to use the word **the** projects the speaker's attitude, namely, that people have heard about it and have been hearing about it (it is the topic of conversation and gossip) and the listener ought to become one of these people if he is not already one of them.

Comment: Well, obviously, I don't agree with that interpretation and it does not accurately describe usage/what's going on. You might give the pdf by Epstein a read.

Comment: *We were having a great evening picnic until the mosquitoes hit.* Which mosquitoes? The ones I am going to tell you about and which form the topic I wish to introduce. You don't know anything about them yet.

Comment: But yes I do know about the mosquitoes. *Everyone* knows about the mosquitoes. He might or might not intend to say anything more about them. Now, if he had said "a great picnic until **the** bling-blongs hit", something unknown, he is intentionally subverting the conventional expectation with **the** for rhetorical purposes: he does intend to tell the listener what the bling-blongs are, **the** signaling that they are a topic of imminent discourse yadda yadda yadda.  Like Cowper's **the** history...

Comment: Indeed, no one knows anything about  ***the** bling-bongs*. But the speaker is not "intentionally subverting the conventional expectation with *the* for rhetorical purposes." This is true only if you describe the usage of *the* in the way you do. I'm saying, after Epstein, et al.,that this description is faulty and does not describe how native speakers use *the*. The use of ***the** bling-bongs* is in accordance with how speakers use it, and so is *the mosquitoes* in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interpret the statement.

> Chlorine(VII) oxide reacts with water to give **a** very strong acid, (*which is*) chloric(VII) acid...

Here using an indefinite article is OK, considering that there are many strong acids, and chloric(VII) acid is just one of them.

> Chlorine(VII) oxide reacts with water to give **the** very strong acid, chloric(VII) acid...

Here using the definite article is OK, considering that you are specifically naming chloric(VII) acid.